# How to receive dividend in INDIA

Tags: india, dividends, wire-transfer

I have shares of City Union bank for more than a year. I have my trading account with HDFC Securities linked with my HDFC bank account. City union bank has announced dividend and I have not received any amount in my bank account till now. Karvy Registrar is the registrar company.

I have contacted HDFC Securities about this and they have asked me to contact HDFC bank to enable ECS in my bank account. Will this be sufficient? How will the Registrar know about the my bank account details and How will it be credited to my bank account?

Please let me know if we need to follow the procedure repetitively for every company's share we hold.

Comment: Since Karvy is in the loop. Worth reading this: https://karisma.karvy.com/html/KarismaFaqs/Karisma_Faqs.html#dividendIhave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned where you Demat Account is. I assume it is with HDFC.

You would need to visit a HDFC Demat Servicing Branch. Fill out a form that links your HDFC Bank Account to the Demat Account. This needs to be done one time. All the companies would use the address mentioned on the Demat Account and the Bank Details mentioned on the demat Account.